# Is there a Feed The Beast bee breeding flowchart?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-forestry

I need a flowchart of some kind to see how to get to certain bees. Does anybody has a flowchart or an app in which I can see the certain bees and how to get them?

Comment: Can you use the mod NEI for this? It comes with most modpacks and allow you press R when hovering a bee in your inventory to see its recipes, navigate using right and left buttons

Comment: In NEI you can only see the hive bees and the bees you allready got (the last ones only from an inventory not in the list on the right). So it's pretty useless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a quick google search give me this.
(Credit belongs solely to plornt from r/feedthebeast)
this just contains Forestry bees
[image]

Here is a web page providing a breeding chart for a select few mod packs which may more may not have all the bees you after.

Sebastian Fischer is maintaining this site
http://bees.fischer.im/

[image: Bees lite]
a more extensive image and details can be found here [Minecraft forums post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/mods-discussion/1387639-forestry-bee-breeding-guide-with-sengirs?page=10)
[master apiarists database](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dYRX765cAt7HOfX_n0zPityzXzqjCDZkZv7hdYbmU50/edit#gid=0)

References

- [Feed the beast forum post](http://forum.feed-the-beast.com/threads/bee-breeding-platinum.10493/)
- Google
- Minecraft forms

Comment: awesome there is a more detailed one in the link below the picture; have a look about halfway down the page for a spoiler tag

Comment: Yeah I saw it..